# how to set bootstrap date time picker value from ISO 8601 Utc format?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

Hi i am using bootstrap date time picker in client side. Getting and setting value is achieved by 
following knockout binding.

```
 ko.bindingHandlers.datetimepicker = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};
            $(element).datetimepicker(options);
            ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function (event) {
                var value = valueAccessor();
                if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
                    var observable = valueAccessor();
                    observable($(element).data("DateTimePicker").getDate()._d);
                }
            });
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            if ($(element)) {
                var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

                $(element).data("DateTimePicker").setDate(value);
            }
        }
    };
```

when i sent data to server using web api  its in  **iso 8601** format (ex) 2012-07-27T18:51:45.53403Z (UTC) and its stored.  When i retrieve data from server using jquery ajax, the date picker is updated using same binding. But it does not show value corresponds to local? How can i achieve that using same binding?

Comment: so does the knockout binding currently show anything at all?

Comment: please share more data . is any thing binded to text-box on-load (if saved) . if not binded you need same `2012-07-27T18:51:45.53403Z` to be binded after save n load ? or ?